# View not clickable after translate in CoordinatorLayot

Tags: java, android, coordinator-layout

I have a ConstraintLayout wrapping my FABs section in the bottom right of the app. I use a layout and not only the buttons because I have more views all around the FABs (they are omitted in the example below, the real layout is more complex). The layout has a CoordinatorLayout as main parent. I have two FABs, one near to the other, when I click the first one the second animates and move up using ViewPropertyAnimations, then I click the second one and other views should appear. ISSUE IS: the translated FAB isn't clickable. I can click on it before the animation starts but not after translation.

[image: not clickable fab]

What I've found so far:

- If I leave only  CoordinatorLayout  and FAbs buttons --> OK, click works after translate
- If I leave only ConstraintLayout and FAbs buttons --> OK, click works after translate
- If I leave CoordinatorLayout , ConstraintLayout and FAbs buttons --> KO, click doesn't work after translate
- If I replace ConstraintLayout with LinearLayout --> KO, click doesn't work after translate

Can you help me to fix this?

Dependencies versions

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
```

Fragment layout (it's a simplified version, the real one has many views)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false" >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom" >

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/fab1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/fab1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fab1" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            android:focusable="true" />
        
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Animation code

```
FloatingActionButton fab1 = requireView().findViewById(R.id.fab1);
FloatingActionButton fab2 = requireView().findViewById(R.id.fab2);

fab1.setOnClickListener(v -> fab2.animate().translationY(-200));
fab1.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
    fab2.animate().translationY(0);
    return true;
});

fab2.setOnClickListener(v -> Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I am having the same problem.

Comment: I have used MotionLayout, with a  transition that adds a margin at the bottom of the second FAB. Not sure it's the idea solution though. I've been reported of some slowness on older devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems solved with constraintlayout:2.1.0